# How do I control the alert use detox in iOS?

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, detox

[image]

I tried using the following to push the OK button, but it does not work.
await element (by.text ('Hello')). tap ();

https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/
There is a note, but it does not seem to be about how to control the system pop-up window.

If you know, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been able to do the following to tap on a native iOS alert.

```
await element(by.label('OK').and(by.type('_UIAlertControllerActionView'))).tap();
```

I got the solution from here [Detox: iOS Simulator how to confirm alert message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522081/detox-ios-simulator-how-to-confirm-alert-message)

Comment: Thank you. It works. :)
It would be nice if the appium supports inspect.

Comment: Is there anyway to find out the UI element Types using Detox Expo?

Comment: @srikanth I don't think you can attach the hierarchy debugger to an Expo app. I maybe wrong, but I don't work with Expo so I cannot speak intelligently about it.