# How to tap on Allow button on permission pop up

Tags: javascript, react-native, detox

I am trying to click on the Allow button using Detox.

[image]

I have tried the following:

[Detox: iOS Simulator how to confirm alert message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522081/detox-ios-simulator-how-to-confirm-alert-message)

I have also tried targeting the "Allow" button by `element(by.label('Allow')).tap()` and also `by.text`

I do not want to set location permissions upon app launch. I would like to simulate a user allowing and not allowing location permissions.

Comment: Have you figure this out?

Answer (score 16):

In your `init.js` file you can allow the permissions:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  await detox.init(config, { launchApp: false });
  await device.launchApp({newInstance: true, permissions: {notifications: 'YES'}});
});
```

Permissions:

```
calendar=YES|NO
camera=YES|NO
contacts=YES|NO
health=YES|NO
homekit=YES|NO
location=always|inuse|never
medialibrary=YES|NO
microphone=YES|NO
motion=YES|NO
notifications=YES|NO
photos=YES|NO
reminders=YES|NO
siri=YES|NO
```

You can check the documentation here: https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/detox/test/e2e/13.permissions.test.js

Comment: This allows the permission, but people on my team want an actual click on the permission popup when the app loads...like a user would see and interact with.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using Detox. The alert is presented from a different process, while Detox operates strictly in the app's process realm.

Answer (score 0):

To "Allow" I have used this with success:

```
element(by.type('_UIAlertControllerActionView')).atIndex(1);
```

And for "Don't Allow", this should work:

```
return element(by.type('_UIAlertControllerActionView')).atIndex(0);
```

Comment: This is for normal alerts, not system alerts, such as permissions.