# Detox. Click on IOS native system pop-up doesn't work

Tags: detox

This is the confirmation alert pop-up I got after login into the application via google sso.

[Native pop-up screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGOKC.png)

And i've got the issue with clicking on 'Continue' button in this pop-up. I saw a few discussions already about this kind of issues, but nothing helped me.
This what i have tried - [Detox: iOS Simulator how to confirm alert message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522081/detox-ios-simulator-how-to-confirm-alert-message), but it didn't work.
Also, I've opened an application in appium app to see the exact element name there, tried to use it in test, but didn't get any success.

[Appium screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZEdo.png)

This is the way how I interact with the element

```
it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('hostname-input'))).toBeVisible();
    await element(by.id('hostname-input')).typeText('companyName');
    await element(by.id('hostname-submit-button')).tap();
    await element(by.id('googleAuthButton')).tap();
    //  XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Continue"]
    await waitFor(element(by.type('XCUIElementTypeButton')))
      .toExist()
      .withTimeout(10000);
    await element(
      by.name('Continue').and(by.type('XCUIElementTypeButton')),
    ).tap();
  });
```

and this is the error:

```
Element matcher: ((!(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView')) && ((kindOfClass('(null)') && isNotNil) && !(kindOfClass('UIAccessibilityTextFieldElement')))) || (((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && parentThatMatches(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))) && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && parentThatMatches(((kindOfClass('(null)') && isNotNil) && !(kindOfClass('UIAccessibilityTextFieldElement')))))))
```

Any ideas on how that could be resolved?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a helper function:

```
const alertsHelper = async (name) => {
    await element(by.label(name).and(by.type('_UIAlertControllerActionView'))).tap();
  };

export default alertsHelper;
```

Used like this:

`await alertsHelper('Continue');`